# AbstractFactory with generic types in Java: a design problem

Tags: java, design-patterns, generics, interface, abstract-factory

I have the following 2 interfaces accordingly to abstract factory pattern:

```
public interface GenericObjectInterface<T extends Number>{
    public T getResult();
}
public interface AbstractFactoryInterface{
    public <T extends Number> GenericObjectInterface<T> createGenericObject();
}
```

I have an abstract class implementing GenericObject, but it's still unaware of the concrete type (it does only generic operations on Number):

```
public abstract class GenericAbstractClass<T extends Number> implements GenericObjectInterface<T>{   }
```

Then I have a series of concrete class extending that perform generic parameter substitution:

```
public class IntegerObject extends GenericAbstractClass<Integer>{
     public Integer getResult(){}
}
....
```

Now, from inside an implementation of the factory I build the concrete type, that's implementing GenericObjectInterface but has lost it's generic parameter:

```
public class ConcreteFactory{
    public <T extends Number> GenericObjectInterface<T> greateGenericObject(Class<T> c){
         if (c.class.isInstance(Integer.class)){
             IntegerObject obj = new IntegerObject();
             //I would like to return obj
             GenericObjectInterface<T> a = new IntegerObject(); //errror
             GenericAbstractClass<T> a = new IntegerObject(); //errror

             return a;
          }else if (c.class.isInstance(Double.class)){
          }
    }
}
```

I would like to return obj that implements GenericObjectInterface but I don't know how can I do it. 
how can I solve this?

I'm used to abstract factory but I've never used it with generics. Am I doing some mistakes in interpreting the pattern?

Comment: You have a very inconsistent example.  What is `IntegerCell`?  What is "o"?  Do you mean "obj"?

Comment: @MarkPeters : sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: The assignment doesn't work because IntegerObject is a GenericAbstractClass<Integer> but in this generic method T might be Double.

Comment: `c.class.isInstance(Integer.class)` doesn't make sense. `Integer.class` is a `Class` and you know what classes it is an instance of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your method returns an `IntegerObject` why don't you just return `GenericObjectInterface<Integer>`? You already know the parameter type.

In that case, just add a generic parameter to `AbstractFactoryInterface`, too:

```
public interface AbstractFactoryInterface<T extends Number> { ... }

public class ConcreteFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface<Integer> { ... }
```

In your implementation the type of `T` would be inferred from the assignment, and thus you could do this:

```
 GenericObjectInterface<Double> g = new ConcreteFactory().greateGenericObject();
```

In that case `T` would be `Double` but you'd use `Integer` internally, resulting in this:

```
GenericObjectInterface<Double> a = new IntegerCell();
```

Since the compiler can't ensure that `T` will always be of type `Integer` it won't allow you to do that assignment.

Comment: I'm not sure of have understand your point. The create method shouldn't alway return an GenericObjectInterface<Integer>, could be also Double and so on. So I haven't parametrized the class itself but the method only.

Comment: @Heisenbug, since you added the generics to the method only (and no method parameter like in Mark's suggestion) the type will be inferred from the call, i.e. from the type it is assigned to. Thus the `Double` example above would result in the method being called with `T=Double`.

Comment: @Heisenbug if the method should determine what type to return you have only a few options: make a factory class per type (`IntegerFactory`, `DoubleFactory` etc.) or pass the information you need to determine the type (most likely a  `Class` parameter) to the method. You can't read the type of `T` at runtime when it is inferred by the call only.

Comment: I understand that. The only thing I don't understand is if it is possible to return IntegerObject without a cast.

Comment: @Heisenbug it should be possible with a solution that defines `T=Integer` at compile time, e.g. by making a concrete class per return type. Passing the parameter class would require you to do the cast, or return `GenericObjectInterface<?>`, if that's ok for you.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract factory is characterized by the factory method returning an interface or abstract class reference instead of the concrete reference.  It does **not** extend to type parameters.

Think of it this way:  should you be able to do this?

```
public class ConcreteListFactory {
    public <T> List<T> createList() {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

What if the caller wanted a `List<Integer>`?

If you want your factory to return a generified type, you should have your concrete class accept the type parameter.  Otherwise have your factory method return a `GenericObjectInterface<Integer>`.

Alternatively, you could have your method accept a type token (`Integer.class`).  For example:

```
public <T extends Number> GenericObjectInterface<T> createGenericObject(Class<T> clazz) {
    if ( clazz.equals(Integer.class) ) {
        return (GenericObjectInterface<T>) new IntegerObject();
    }
}
```

This will result in an unchecked cast warning but you can prove to yourself that it is safe, and thus suppress the warning or ignore it.

Comment: yes. I'm doing like  that. I edited my question because it was a bit unclear. But the point is, am I forced to do that cast? Is it a bad thing? am I implementing right abstract factory with generics this way?

Comment: @Heisenbug: You're still missing the cast, but yes this way is safe if you pass in the type parameter; otherwise you have no way of knowing which type the caller requested.  In my opinion the better way is to type the entire factory like Thomas suggested.  Then `ConcreteFactory` would implement `AbstractFactoryInterface<Integer>`.  Remember: the goal in generics is to create generic code that is agnostic to its type.  **If you find yourself specializing based on the type parameter, you're no longer gaining anything from generics.**

Comment: I don't want to parametrize the whole class, only the method because Integer could be substituted with Double and so on.

Comment: @Heisenbug: But my point is, you're no longer using it generically.  You have provided no benefit to the clients of your method over just providing different methods (`createIntegerObject`, `createDoubleObject`, etc).  If both the caller **and** the library need to know the *actual* type, making the method generic doesn't help you at all.

Comment: you are right. Effectively I could simply use more methods. But my doubts were't about this (even if your points are helpful). My question is: is impossible to return : return (GenericObjectInterface<T>) new IntegerObject();
without casting it?

Comment: @Heisenbug: Yes, it's impossible without casting it.  Casting is your way of telling the compiler "I know this is a dirty hack, but I've looked at it and am telling you it's safe.  Now let me do it."

Answer (score 1):

Generally, factories are not implemented as generics because you can't examine the type of the generic to determine the type of object to create (you can't do T.getClass) which is why @Mark's example causes the class to be passed in as an argument.

I think, more usually you would have multiple concrete factories. One for each Number type that you intend to support.

```
public interface AbstractFactoryInterface<T extends Number> {
    public GenericObjectInterface<T> createGenericObject();
}


class IntegerFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface<Integer>...
class LongFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface<Long>...
```

You could then create a Map<Class, AbstractFactoryInterface>...

```
Map<Class, AbstractFactoryInterface> myMap = ...;
myMap.put(Integer.class, new IntegerFactory());
myMap.put(Long.class, new LongFactory ());
```

Answer (score 1):

casting is perfectly fine here. if `c==Integer.class`, then `T=Integer`, casting `GOI<Object>` to `GOI<T>` is absolutely correct. It is a checked cast because you have checked that `T=Integer` before casting, therefore the unchecked warning can be legitimately suppressed.